# How can i increase my fps output ? (ffmpeg, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm having quite the trouble understanding how fps output works.

I have a video workflow through node and ffmpeg that transform picture into scrolling videos, here is the command :

```
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'color=s=1280x720', '-loop', '1', '-i', `${path}/${video.name}`, '-filter_complex', `[1:v]scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p,fps=fps=60[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-\'t*h*0.02\'[v]`, '-map', '[v]', '-t', `${clipDuration}`, `./${path}/${video.name}-wip.mp4`])
ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`${data}`);
});
ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
  const ffmpeg2 = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', `./${path}/${video.name}-wip.mp4`, '-vf', `tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=3,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=${clipDuration + 2}`, `./${path}/${video.name}.mp4`])
  ffmpeg2.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
  });
  ffmpeg2.on('close', (code) => {
    resolve();
  });
})
```

First ffmpeg command create a scrolling video from picture,
second ffmpeg command add a fade out transition and a pause to this video.

FPS output for this is 25. How can i increase it to 60 so that scrolling isn't stuttering anymore ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well I followed the documentation, see : http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const ffmpeg2 = spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', `./${path}/${video.name}-wip.mp4`, '-vf', `framerate=fps=60,tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=3,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=${clipDuration + 2}`, `./${path}/${video.name}.mp4`])
```

Note this from https://superuser.com/questions/1265642/ffmpeg-slideshow-with-crossfade:

```
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -vf "framerate=fps=60" -codec:v mpeg4 out.mp4
```

Comment: my fps was already at 25 wich is default. But thank you, it was actually this second pipe that was deleting frame from the original cause of default parameter. Once i set the "framerate=fps=60" on it too, everything went smooth and my final ouput is 60fps ;)

Comment: yeah i figured all you needed was to set the parameter, i didnt read your full question, ive updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In commmand ， Use it

`ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -vf "framerate=fps=60" -codec:v mpeg4 out.mp4`